# Order multiple fields by custom order, empty fields last

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am editing this question as the original was quite poorly worded, and had incorrect information that I didn't see until after it was answered, which understandably caused confusion. Since I can't delete it, I will attempt to edit it the best I can.

I have 3 fields in a large table that store information pertaining to a timeline, and I would like to apply custom ordering to all of them.

The "**Date**" column holds either a year OR an era name. There are 3 options for the era name in this example:  *Early Era*, *Mid Era*, and *Late Era*. If a year is present in the "Date" column, in the same row the "**Era**" and/or "**Era2**" columns may optionally have an era name. There will never be a value in the "**Era2**" column without there also being a value in the "**Era**" column.

I would like to perform the following sort:

- I would like to put rows with all three columns empty at the very bottom.
- I would then like all the "**Date**" columns that have **only** a
  year -- with "**Era**" and "**Era2**" columns in that row empty -- toward the bottom. The year may be sorted in ascending order.
- Then, I would like to order any column with an era name
  ("**Date**", "**Era**", or "**Era2**" column) with a predefined
  custom order (see below).  Rows with a year defined in the "**Date**" and a value in the "**Era**" or "**Era2**" columns will sort before "**Date**" columns which contain only an era name.

Example of Predefined Order:

```
 ("Early Era","Mid Era","Late Era")
```

Current Unsorted Table:

```
Date           | Era           | Era2
-------------- |-------------- |-------------- 
         1991  | Early Era     |
         1992  | Early Era     |
    Early Era  |               |
         1999  | Mid Era       | Late Era
         1999  | Mid Era       | Early Era
      Mid Era  |               |  
     Late Era  |               |  
    Early Era  |               |  
               | Mid Era       |  
               | Late Era      |        
         2009  |               |    
     Late Era  |               |            
         2014  | Late Era      |
               |               |              
         2015  |               |         
         1992  |               |            
         1999  |               |            
         1992  | Early Era     |
```

Desired Result After Sort:

```
Date           | Era           | Era2
-------------- |-------------- |-------------- 
         1991  | Early Era     |
         1992  | Early Era     |
         1992  | Early Era     |       
    Early Era  |               |        
    Early Era  |               |
         1999  | Mid Era       | Early Era
         1999  | Mid Era       | Late Era
      Mid Era  |               |  
               | Mid Era       |  
         2014  | Late Era      |
     Late Era  |               |
     Late Era  |               |    
               | Late Era      |  
         1992  |               |  
         1999  |               |                     
         2009  |               |              
         2015  |               |         
               |               |
```

Current code which doesn't fully work, but it's mostly there:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN Date LIKE '%Era%' OR Era LIKE '%Era%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
        CASE WHEN Date != '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
        FIELD(CASE WHEN Era = '' THEN Date ELSE Era END, 'Late Era','Mid Era','Early Era') DESC, 
        CASE WHEN Era LIKE '%Era%'  THEN 0
             WHEN Date LIKE '%Era%' THEN 1 END;
```

Undesired Order With Current Code, After Sort

```
Date           | Era           | Era2
-------------- |-------------- |-------------- 
         1991  | Early Era     |
         1992  | Early Era     |
         1992  | Early Era     |       
    Early Era  |               |        
    Early Era  |               |
         1999  | Mid Era       | Late Era
         1999  | Mid Era       | Early Era
      Mid Era  |               |  
         2014  | Late Era      |
     Late Era  |               |  
     Late Era  |               |  
               | Mid Era       |  
               | Late Era      |        
         2009  |               |              
         2015  |               |         
         1992  |               |            
         1999  |               |           
               |               |
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/CAMA42792

Note that the era names in the "**Era2**" column are not sorted correctly. Also, the era names in the "**Era**" column (those with an empty "**Date**" column) are still not sorted correctly -- they should be grouped with like era names. Thirdly, the years at the very bottom are in the correct position, they are just not in ascending order. Hope that makes sense, and please let me know if there's anything in need of further explanation, I understand it's a bit convoluted. Thank you in advance for any help.

**Edit** - This is a very different question than the original, but hopefully it clarifies and corrects the issues present in my initial version. If the mods deem it best, they may delete this question and I will be happy to create a new one.

Comment: What on Earth are these dates?  They must be strings, and you should never do that.  As you are seeing, it makes sorting (and just about everything else) a real nightmare.  Instead, store all date information in a bona-fide date column.  Make life happy, not sad.

Comment: I needed the flexibility of putting an era name when the date is unknown. If you had read the thread, my real problem is sorting multiple columns by a predefined order. The column with just dates go at the bottom anyway, so that isn't really the problem here.

Comment: It very much appears to be an issue because your output dates are sorted.  Are you saying the dates can appear in any order?

Comment: No, I'm saying I already correctly sorted the dates separate from their Eras. My difficulty is sorting them WITH their eras. Did you not read the thread? I feel I already covered this. The last table is my current code output -- notice the dates are in order apart from their eras.

Comment: Critiquing the way it is set up will do me no good. This is the current set up I have to work with.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I owe you an apology, as the entire premise of my needing to sort dates was based off of my reading my table incorrectly -- I only need the year. So sorry for confusing everything and making it harder than it had to be, and for in any way being unprofessional or tense in my responses. Thanks again for your answer, as it's gotten me most the way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Date LIKE '%Era%' OR Era LIKE '%Era%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN Date IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    FIELD(COALESCE(Era, Date), 'Late Era','Mid Era','Early Era') DESC, 
    CASE WHEN Era LIKE '%Era%'  THEN 0
         WHEN Date LIKE '%Era%' THEN 1 END;
```

This query is based around what I saw in your expected output. That is, it selects the following in order of precedence:

- records where `Date` or `Era` have the text `Era` appear before records which do not have this text
- records having a `NULL` date come after those whose date is not `NULL`
- then order by early, mid, late, `NULL` (you almost already have this)
- finally put records with a `Date` era after those with an era in the `Era` column

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 2):

The person who answered this originally gave me a partially working answer, and in the comments above encouraged me to edit his answer once I had the full solution. Once I obtained the full working solution, I edited his answer, however those edits were not approved. So I wanted to post the full working solution for anyone who finds it useful:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
      CASE WHEN concat(Era,Era,Date) LIKE '%Era%' THEN 0 else 1 end,
      FIELD(CASE WHEN Era = '' THEN Date ELSE Era END, 'Late Era','Mid Era','Early Era') desc,
      CASE WHEN Date!='' THEN 0 ELSE 1 end,
      CASE WHEN date not like '%Era%' THEN 0 else 1 end,
      date, Era2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7d9d8/3/0)

Comment: Good on you for nailing down the query, but in general if you find yourself writing a query like this for a simple question on a single table, it might indicate bad design.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I had the consult of an experienced software programmer and coder when I set the design up, and if you understood the structure of the website, you might understand why this design is beneficial. However since it is unnecessary to describe in detail my particular context, I will leave it there.